# Adding a file into a folder in Zip file PHP

Tags: php

My zip file's name is "ZIPFOLDER". And when it is unzipped, the folder's name is "UNZIPFOLDER".

My zip folder structure is very simple. It has only one folder

```
UNZIPFOLDER
 |
 |- Folder
 |
 |- XMLFile
 |
```

Now I want to create a NewFolder in the existing MyFolder name in my zip file like:

```
UNZIPFOLDER
 |
 |- Folder
 |  |
 |  |- NewFolder
 |  |
 |
 |- XMLFile
 |
```

What's wrong with the following code:

```
$zip = new ZipArchive();
if (!($zip->open('ZIPFOLDER') === TRUE)) {
   return false;
}

$folder = 'NewFolder';
$zip->addEmptyDir("Folder/{$folder}");

$zip->close();
```

The result is not as I expected when I unzip the NewFolder is a separate folder.

```
 ZIPFOLDER
 |
 |- UNZIPFOLDER
 |  |
 |  |- Folder
 |  |
 |  |- XMLFile
 |
 |  
 |- NewFolder
 |
```

In conclusion: the bug occurs when the zip file's name and the folder's name (when it is unzipped) are different.

Comment: Your question is not clear, do you want to add a file into a folder of your zip or do you want to add an empty folder?
There are some bugs in PHP Zip capabillities, If you want to add a file to a not existing subfolder, try with `$zip->addFromString('Folder/newFolder/test.txt', 'file content goes here');` this worked for me a while back.

Comment: In the above example, either I add an empty folder or a file into an existing folder in a zip file, it still creates a separate folder outside.

Comment: This is not a question, it is an observation or even a bugreport. Please understand, that you did not ask any question and this might be the main reason why nobody answers or comments on your observation. Try with something like "How can I add subfolders into zip archives with PHP?" and reask your question or fill a bugreport for PHP.

Comment: I don't know whether it's a bug from PHP or not. So that's why I show my code and possibly you discover something wrong from my code. And even it's a bug from PHP, so what I ask is for a workaround. Thanks.

Comment: for a workaround, just unzip the whole zip to a directory, do your things with mkdir, file_put_contents etc. functions, zip the directory content and delete it afterwards. ;)